# How to save consoleText after running jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

In Execute Shell I used command wget http://jenkins:8080/job/Jenkins_name_job/${BUILD_ID}/consoleText

I want to use Archive the artifacts. But can't understand how.
In Post-build Actions / Archive the artifacts I wrote ${Build_ID}/logs/* .
But got the error:
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "184/logs/*". Configuration error?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:
wget http://jenkins:8080/job/Jenkins_name_job/${BUILD_ID}/consoleText

In Post-build Actions / Archive the artifacts I wrote ${Build_ID}/**

Answer (score 0):

Actually to archive the artifacts it should be `${Build_ID}/logs/*.(log file type like log)`

References: [My own Jenkins](https://ci-xiurobert.rhcloud.com)